# Virtual machine gets a new IP address every few minutes

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, 16.10

I have Lubuntu 16.10 as host operating system. When calling `cat /etc/*-release`, I get this:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=yakkety
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.10 (Yakkety Yak)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.10"
VERSION_ID="16.10"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=yakkety
UBUNTU_CODENAME=yakkety
```

Every package is up-to-date on the host.

I have installed VirtualBox. Within VirtualBox, I have created a new virtual machine with Ubuntu 16.04 Server LTS. But the network behaviour of this Ubuntu in the virtual machine is odd. Every five minutes or so, it gets a new IP address.

Why is that? I just installed it. How can I solve this problem?

** Edit **

When created the guest machine I set in the network setting the setting `Network bridge`, so the guest should get it's own IP address, which every machine connecting to my router here gets through DHCP.

Comment: Does the host have a similar behaviour?

Comment: @George: Nope, the behaviour is only on the guest machine. On host, everything is normal.

Comment: Is the guest network setting NAT?

Comment: Set your VM guest OS network to `Bridged Adapter`.